# which of the following statements are true?? ( Calculus and Differential equations)(NBHM-$2014$)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Which of the following statements are ??

a. Let $\phi$ be a non-negative and continuously differentiable function on $(0,\infty)$ such that $\phi'(x)\le\phi(x)$ for all $x$ $\in (0,\infty)$. Then

$$lim_{x\to \infty}\phi(x)=0$$

b. Let $\phi$ be a non-negative function continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and differentiable on     $(0,\infty)$ such that $\phi(0)=0$ and such that   $\phi'(x)\le\phi(x)$ for all $x$ $\in   (0,\infty)$. Then $\phi=0$.

c. Let $\phi$ be a non-negative function continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and such that 
      $$\phi(x) \le \int_{0}^{x}\phi(t) dt$$ for all $x \in [0,\infty)$. Then $\phi=0$.

Answer (score 2):

> **Hint(Grownwall's Inequality)**
>
> If 
>   $$f(t)\leq K+\int_a^tf(s)g(s)ds,$$
>   then
>   $$f(t)\leq K\exp(\int_a^tg(s)ds)$$
>
> And $K\geq 0$; $f,g$ is nonnegative continuous in $[a,b]$.

Comment: so (b) and (c) are right??

Comment: (a) and (b) are right.

Comment: (c) is lack of $\phi(0)=0$

Comment: how can (a) be right?? suppose $\phi(x)=e^x$??

Comment: in (c) $\phi(0)=0$...

Comment: Ok... I'm wrong in (a) and sorry for it. So as you say, (b)(c) is right.

Comment: @ Prayagdeep : how can you say $\phi = 0$, please tell me

Answer (score -1):

All of them are wrong.

For statement 1, consider $\phi(x) = e^x$. For statement 2, consider $\phi(x) = e^x - 1$. For statement 3, consider $\phi(x) = e^x$.

Comment: Your examples for statement 2 and statement 3 are wrong.